# Access relationship looping example

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, relationship

I am struggling with some basics of MS Access 2010/2013. I am not sure if I did hit the limit of it or if I am just using the wrong procedure. I will explain what i need.

Take for example 5 items in a shop, where 3 are items and 2 are a combination of items.
They need to be presented in the same matter, i.e. the combinations of products (bundles), needs to have a number in the same series as those it contains. See figure below:

[image]

So far, I created 2 tables. 1 for stand alone products and 1 for bundles. Bundles should be able to include other bundles (This is where i get the problems).

If someone orders, lets say, 10 times Items 5, I need Access to count how many Motherboards (Item 1), how many CPU (item 2) etc. I need a full list of those items, so i hopefully should get a list that says:

10 x Motherboard

10 x CPU

10 x Cabinet

So i don't have to dig into each bundle. Hence, as i see it, the relationsship runs in sort of a loop.

I identify the items to be either a combination or product by a column with "yes/no".

If you have any suggestions, let me know, or if you think i hit the limit.
An alternative method is welcome, as well as a sample of a simple Access database.

For the record, the system is gonna be used for huge machines, creating lists of bolts, nuts, electrical equipment etc. The above is only to explain my thoughts.

Best Regards, Emil.

Comment: You may wish to read http:\\r937.com\relational.html. Your table design is not good.

Comment: What you are describing is a bill of materials database. If you google it, you will find a great deal of information. google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=bill+of+materials+database+design&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_en&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=active&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl. Additionally, you might want to consider SQL Server. It has a hierarchical table type. The Express edition of SQL Server is free.

Comment: This looks like it should be three tables instead of one.  Items, Bundles, and BundleDetails.  Would make the resulting calculations somewhat easier to accomplish.